# Tabulate intersection, but I need it with null values too, not just with matching intersect

Tags: intersection, null, arcgis-10.7, values, tabulate

I have problem with tabulate intersection tool (In ArcGIS - ArcMap 10.7.1). The number of data is 1298 with 500 m buffer. Then i have polygons, that I need to process. I run the tool,  but get the table with only 170 records, that is matching, but it is not all what i need. I need the complete data even with null fields, where the tool doesn't find the intersect. Is here any way, how to get table with the null values and intersect values together in tabulate intersection?

Comment: Which software are you working with? Please edit your question and the tags so it contains this information.

Comment: Thank you for reacting, i work in arcgis 10.7.1.